# IOS 8 Addressbook kABPersonEmailProperty

Tags: ios8, abpeoplepickerview

I developed one application. It is working perfectly in IOS 7. But IOS 8 I have issues. I implement the function get the contact information from address book.

So I implement the method

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{

    [self gettingContactInfo:person];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    return NO;
}
```

This method is perfectly working in IOS 7. But IOS 8 not working.

So I developed other method

```
-(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{

    [self gettingContactInfo:person];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But after this method I am always getting email is empty. What is the mistake i did?

Email getting method

```
 _emailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    ABMutableMultiValueRef emailsRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emailsRef) > 0) {
        // collect all emails in array
        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(emailsRef); i++) {
            CFStringRef emailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailsRef, i);

            NSString *currentEmail=(__bridge NSString *)emailRef;
            NSLog(@"%@",currentEmail);

            [_contactInfoDict setObject:currentEmail forKey:CONTACT_EMAIL];

            [_emailArray addObject:currentEmail];

            CFRelease(emailRef);
        }
    }

    if (emailsRef) {
        CFRelease(emailsRef);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `NSString *currentEmail = CFBridgingRelease(emailRef);`?